# Ubuntu Shellscript Path Variable

Tags: bash, shell, path, cron

I have the following Shellscript that I call from my crontab, which works fine until it calls php code that involves shell commands like wget or find.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/opt/server/php/bin:/usr/bin/wget:/bin/egrep:/usr/bin/find
cd /opt/server/apache2/htdocs/webapp/ 
php oil refine job:handler
```

For each Command I did a *which command* to look up the path, then I added it to the Path Variable. Nevertheless it does not find the commands and I get messages like these:

```
sh: wget: not found
sh: find: not found
```

How would I fix this? I know that this is a common problem, but I didn't find a good explanation for this here on stackoverflow. Also: I know that calling the script from bash versus crontab might result in different enviroment settings, but eitherway I get these Errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good sir, the `PATH` is a string that describes the **directories** that contain executables, not the executables themselves.

Perhaps use something like this

```
PATH=/opt/server/php/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```